# remove lines containing date and another expression

Tags: linux, sed

Sorry for my simple question. but I am looking for a way to remove lines in a file which start with a string contain 2 or 3 capital letters and also contain date. for example:

```
ABC/ Something comes here, 29/1/2001.
```

in the first step of writing such script I used this code to find and show the lines which contain date, but it doesn't work.

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+//' myfile.txt
```

what is wrong in this code, and how should I change it to do what I want?

Bests.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r -e '/[A-Z]+.*[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/p;d' # on Mac OSX: sed -E -e ...
```

And then to just delete the lines do something like...

```
'/[A-Z]+.*[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try with:

```
sed -e '/^[A-Z]\{2,3\}.*[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{4\}/ d' input-file
```

Explanation:

```
^                  Match at the beginning of the pattern.
[A-Z]\{2,3\}       Match two or three uppercase ASCII letters.
.*                 Match anything.
[0-9]\{1,2\}\/     Match the day, one or two digits, and the separator.
[0-9]\{1,2\}\/     Same match for the month.
[0-9]\{4\}         Match four digits for the date.
d                  If previous regexp matched, delete the line.
```